# I get an error when I try to load an Image into a Container - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

As you can see (on the images), my Image in that case doesn't load my Logo into the left bottom Container.

Can someone help me? What I'm doing wrong or is it because of the Drawer?

[image: app layout]
[image: pubspec.yaml]
[image: error message]

Comment: Can you try using Image.asset()

Comment: Please include textual content (code, error message, ...) always as `formatted` text in your question description. Content of images cannot be searched; see also [other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5698098). As a new contributor – _Welcom to Stack Overflow_ – you may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your pubspec.yaml doesn't have a correct format and it should as follow:

```yaml
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

That should fix your problem.